# openCV - camera view window has different size of camera resolution

Tags: python, opencv

I have a 720p resolution camera and I'm trying to open the camera in a view window in openCV. here's the code:

```
while(True):
   ret, frame = vid.read()
   if render_poly:
       frame = cv2.polylines(frame, [pts],
                           isClosed, color, thickness)
   cv2.imshow('window', frame)
   key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if key == ord('q'):
       break
   elif key == ord('p'):
       render_poly = not render_poly
```

Before that, I tried to ajust the view window with this code (720p resolution):

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
```

What I expected is `1280x720` view window size, but for some reason I got `1600x900` which caused incorrect positioning of the polygon I'm trying to render, and to solve that I needed to adjust its coordinates by multiplying it with the scale of `1280/1600` in width and `720/900` in height.
Can I skip that proccess (which will be more in the future project) and just to render the camera view on a window with its same resolution size? is it a good idea?

Comment: 720p is normally 1280x720, not 1080x720.  It may have chosen the best res from the camera when it couldn't find an exact match.

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry, I meant 1280, that's what I had in my code

Comment: What's the camera model?

Comment: it's a realtek sunplus laptop webcam

Comment: That's not much help.  Are you on Windows?  If you add `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` to the `VideoCapture` call, does it change?

Comment: scale factor is 1.25... this may be windows desktop "dpi scaling" at work, or not